# Make HTML elements appear into the page

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface, user-experience

I've created an AngularJS single page app, which has chat rooms. I want to have, on my main page (index.html), some kind of JavaScript function which will gradually show text boxes of the rooms I have on my app. Like an old screensaver, each text box with a room name will be appearing on the page (in lets say 5 seconds intervals) on a random not occupied location on the background of the screen.

My question is - in UI/UX terms - what is the best way to present new content from lets say an array of data (in my case some texts array), with intervals of 5 seconds (JavaScript timer?), And makes each data appears out of the blue into the screen (CSS animation?).

Comment: You can create a grid from the entire page, create a template for the element and at an interval create a new element using the template and insert it into an empty space on the grid.

Comment: Please tell us about what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Titus in which web platforme can I build a grid and insert templates into that grid? thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not Sure, But I think you want to achieve something like below https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/autoplay.html